# React Send form data to email

Tags: reactjs, email

I am using create-react-app or my project. I created a form field where I store the data into the state. I would like to send the data as an email, and I'm lost on how to do so.

One of the problems is using create-react-app, I'm not sure where to find my router or server page in node.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Col, Grid, Row, Form, FormGroup, FormControl, 
ControlLabel, Checkbox } from 'react-bootstrap';

export class Contact extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            email: "",
            message: ""
        }
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        const state = this.state;
        state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState(state);
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { name, email, message } = this.state;


    }




    render() {
        const { name, email, message } = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                <Grid>
                    <Row id="contactForm">
                        <Col xs={2}>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={8}>
                            <Form horizontal onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                                <FormGroup >
                                  <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                                    Name
                                  </Col>
                                  <Col sm={10}>
                                    <FormControl required value={name} name="name" type="name" 
                                    placeholder="Name" onChange={this.onChange} />
                                  </Col>
                                </FormGroup>

                                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                                  <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                                    Email
                                  </Col>
                                  <Col sm={10}>
                                    <FormControl required value={email} name="email" type="email" 
                                    placeholder="Email" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                                  </Col>
                                </FormGroup>

                                <FormGroup>
                                    <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} bsSize="lg" sm={2}>
                                        Message
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col sm={10}>
                                        <FormControl required value={message} name="message" componentClass="textarea" style={{ height: 200 }} 
                                        type="message" placeholder="Insert message here" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                                    </Col>
                                </FormGroup>

                                <FormGroup>
                                  <Col smOffset={2} sm={10}>
                                    <Checkbox>Flag as important</Checkbox>
                                  </Col>
                                </FormGroup>

                                <FormGroup>
                                  <Col smOffset={2} sm={10}>
                                    <Button type="submit">
                                      Send
                                    </Button>
                                  </Col>
                                </FormGroup>
                            </Form>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={2}>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send email from my react web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795125/how-to-send-email-from-my-react-web-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that You cannot send mail from the client. You will need to have a server to do so. If you have an api service that your React is consuming from, then it is very possible from there.

Comment: I actually created a node microservice to send emails using nodemailer. Worked like a charm!