# How to send email from my react web application

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i have a single email input field and a button in my app. once i enter the email and click send i would like to send an email with the value entered in the input. i know it cant be done in Reactjs because it is a frontend. How can i do? can someone help?

Comment: Since you tagged `node.js`, do you have a Node server running?

Comment: no i dont.... i thought a mail can be send using node.js... so i tagged it

Answer (score 31):

From a front end client you can send a request to an SMTP server, which will send the email.

[This tutorial](https://blog.mailtrap.io/react-send-email/) runs over how to do that with the emailJS SMTP server, (which allows you to send 200 free emails/month in case free is a priority).

I'll summarize because they didn't cover everything I wanted.

---

### Step1: Install emailJS

Install emailJS via

```
npm install emailjs-com
```

or

```
yarn add emailjs-com
```

[Source](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/sdk/installation/)

> If you are using create-react-app please view the tutorial I mentioned above or this linked source, where they provide instructions on how to include emailJS with create-react-app

### Step 2: Create a form to send the email

This is a code example of a form which sends an email using emailJS, You must replace `'YOUR_SERVICE_ID'`, `'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID'`, and `'YOUR_USER_ID'` with your actual id's(which I will explain where to find in later steps)

```
import React from 'react';
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';

export default function ContactUs() {

  function sendEmail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    //This is important, i'm not sure why, but the email won't send without it

    emailjs.sendForm('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', e.target, 'YOUR_USER_ID')
      .then((result) => {
          window.location.reload()  //This is if you still want the page to reload (since e.preventDefault() cancelled that behavior) 
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
  }

  return (
    <form className="contact-form" onSubmit={sendEmail}>
      <input type="hidden" name="contact_number" />
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="from_name" />
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="from_email" />
      <label>Subject</label>
      <input type="text" name="subject" />
      <label>Message</label>
      <textarea name="html_message" />
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

[Source](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/reactjs/) (I made some adjustments)

- If you don't want your api details to be visible from the client, you would have to make a request (containing the email message, from, to, etc.) to a backend server(which would be set up and running to receive requests) via something like `axios` or `fetch` and then execute the `sendEmail` function from your server

### Step 3: Create an emailJS account

Set up an account at https://www.emailjs.com/

### Step 4: Connect an email account to emailJS and get YOUR_SERVICE_ID

Connect an email by adding a service, in this case I used gmail.

**'YOUR_SERVICE_ID'**(step 2) should be the id beside `Service ID`

[image]

### Step 5: Create a template email message and get YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID

Create a a template by clicking Email Templates in the side nav and selecting create new template. This will create an email outline and give you a template id

You should replace **'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID'**(step 2) with this template id

[image]

Here is an example Email template

[image]

### Step 6: Get YOUR_USER_ID

You can find your userID by going to *Integration -> API*

Replace **'YOUR_USER_ID'**(step 2) with the id under **API Keys -> Public Key**

[image]

---

- If you don't want spam emails, [add Captcha](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/user-guide/adding-captcha-verification/)
- if you change your email password, you have to redo step 4

Comment: Good explanation and its works for me, I think they made some changes inside the API, they will change `OUR_USER_ID` to `Public Key` and you can to found it inside Account > API Keys > *Public Key*

Comment: This is a phenomenal explanation. Much props to you sir! I am curious how you obtained all this information though. I probably didn't take enough time to navigate the docs but nothing I found was as simple and accurate as this. Thank you again!

Comment: This is working fine but  it is loading the whole page in react js. i think this line not required.  window.location.reload()

Answer (score 8):

From frontend only you can trigger mails using an smtp server such as **smtpJS**

Steps to follow is

1. Go to this link [smtpJS](https://www.smtpjs.com/)
2. Click **GetSMTPCredentials** and register.
3. After registering, note down the credentials and click **ENCRYPTSMTPCrendentials**

A sample would be as follows

```
var test={
sendEmail(subject,to,body){
    
    /* SmtpJS.com - v3.0.0 */
    let Email = { send: function (a) { return new Promise(function (n, e) { a.nocache = Math.floor(1e6 * Math.random() + 1), a.Action = "Send"; var t = JSON.stringify(a); Email.ajaxPost("https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtpjs.aspx?", t, function (e) { n(e) }) }) }, ajaxPost: function (e, n, t) { var a = Email.createCORSRequest("POST", e); a.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), a.onload = function () { var e = a.responseText; null != t && t(e) }, a.send(n) }, ajax: function (e, n) { var t = Email.createCORSRequest("GET", e); t.onload = function () { var e = t.responseText; null != n && n(e) }, t.send() }, createCORSRequest: function (e, n) { var t = new XMLHttpRequest; return "withCredentials" in t ? t.open(e, n, !0) : "undefined" != typeof XDomainRequest ? (t = new XDomainRequest).open(e, n) : t = null, t } };

    Email.send({
        SecureToken : process.env.SECURE_TOKEN, // write your secure token
        To : to, // to include multiple emails you need to mention an array
        From : process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
        Subject : subject,
        Body : body
    })
    .then(message=>{
        // alert(message);
    });

    
}
}

 export default test;
```

you can import above js file like below and call the method

```
import test from '../../components/sendEmail'
test.sendEmail("sub","msg");
```

Comment: It shows syntax error for me, any advice to solve?

Answer (score 0):

React is only used for front end purpose so it is not only  enough to send email.

But you can send email from client usingsome external API, like Mailjet, [Gmail Api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/) etc

Answer (score 0):

Look this out [Setting Email without a back end](https://www.abstractapi.com/guides/react-send-email-from-your-app-without-a-backend)

its more handy and gives you all the control