# Send email from React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nodemailer

I have an application, built using React. If I want to send an email to a user after another user successfully completes an action, what are some technologies I need to or can use? To clarify, I have no backend server set up yet.

Comment: React is frontend, emails are sent from a backend server. So React has nothing to do with this. It will greatly depend on the technology stack of your backend server.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795125/how-to-send-email-from-my-react-web-application

Comment: @AlexWayne I was hoping for answers containing technologies to use, not technologies I don't need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check sendgrid! You can do in your backend(nodejs in this case):

```
const SGmail = require ('@sendgrid/mail')
SGmail.setApiKey(process.env.REACT_APP_SG_API)

app.post('/your/endpoint', (req,res) => {
const data = req.body
const mailOptions = {
    from: data.email,
    to:'email@example.com',
    subject:'Subject',
    html:`<p>${data.name}</p>
        <p>${data.email}</p>
        <p>${data.message}</p>`
}
SGmail.send(mailOptions).then((err,res)=>{res.redirect('/')})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/), they offer a generous free tier.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not expected to do the actual email sending, you could, in JS, [build an .eml file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mimemessage) and have the user ["download" it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25911218/2518317). They would then send it in their client of choice.

Otherwise you will need, at the very least, access to a mail server, to send this multipart-mime to, or, a little safer, build the message on the server and send it internally.

Comment: thanks! this is a cool and different way to do it than the other answers!