# Using Sendinblue, mailgun or another email sending platform to send email to myself from a form on a static website

Tags: html, reactjs, email, mailgun, sendinblue

My website is coded up using React.
I want the website to be static, so that I can just put it on Github and host it using Netlify.

The code below is my email form. Currently I am using a php script. I want to change this in order to make my website static. I really just want to know what I have to change the action to on the line `action='./php/sendEmail.php'` so that I no longer have to use php and can just access my sendinblue account(I heard it's free up to a certain point, so that's why I want to use it over mailgun) and send an email to my email address.

```
var Field = (props) => {
    return (
        <input id={props.id} className={props.className} aria-invalid="false" name={props.name} placeholder={props.name} data-aid={props.dataAid} type={props.type} onChange={(e) => dispatch(editValue(e.target.value,item.id)) }></input>
    )
}
Field.defaultProps = { type: 'text'}

var EmailForm = (props) => {

    return (
        <div className="form" data-state="desktop left" data-dcf-columns="4">
            <form action='./php/sendEmail.php' method="post" role="form" aria-label="contact form" className="form_style-wrapper" encType="multipart/form-data">
                <Field id='field1' name='Name' dataAid='nameField' className='field_word required' />
                <Field id='field2' name='Email' dataAid='emailField' className='field_word required' />
                <Field id='field3' name='Phone' dataAid='emailField' type='hidden' className='field_word' />
                <Field id='field4' name='Subject' dataAid='subjectField' className='field_word' />
                <textarea name="Message" className="message" placeholder="Message" data-aid="messageField"></textarea>
                <button className="sendButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">Send</button>                           
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

EmailForm.defaultProps = {
    action: 'handleSubmit'
}
```

Comment: [Here's an answer for emailjs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61582486/6331353), would still like a solution for sendinblue

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the fields on your Sendinblue account and you can just use their REST APIs to send the emails.

You need to create and configure the template though.
https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference#sendtransacemail

An example API call:

```js
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/smtp/email \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'api-key:YOUR_API_KEY' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{  
   "sender":{  
      "name":"Sender Alex",
      "email":"senderalex@example.com"
   },
   "to":[  
      {  
         "email":"testmail@example.com",
         "name":"John Doe"
      }
   ],
   "subject":"Hello world",
   "htmlContent":"<html><head></head><body><p>Hello,</p>This is my first transactional email sent from Sendinblue.</p></body></html>"
}'
```

**Edit:**

If you want to hit the API call, first you need to maintain the form state. So better would be to convert your functional component to stateful component.

You can read more about stateful components here: https://medium.com/@imletaconnoux/stateful-and-stateless-components-in-react-5da5cedb808f

Based on your request I made an example of making an api call (using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)) on form submit. You can use the reference and implement it to your app. You can use [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for the same instead of axios as well

https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-sun-2xpri

Comment: I'm wondering how to write the html/javascript code for my form. I would like the website to be static.

Comment: Can you define 'Static'? And you definitely have to write an API call to get this work!

Comment: I don't want to have a backend, I want to host the websites using github and netlify, but then I have an email form that I want to send emails to one email address

Comment: You don't need to have a backend to send the API call to sendinblue. You can Google how to call an API in Javascript

Comment: Ok, how do I make the api call from my html form

Comment: I gave you the bounty because I'm sure this will help me, but I've looked around a bunch searching for how to make this api call and I can't figure it out, so I'd appreciate if you could show how I could make this call with JS and HTML

Comment: Ok, I think I almost have it, this is what my code is https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-brook-eu56e . I'm getting a 401 error and I think it's because I get this warning on the site ' The transactional platform has not been activated for your account. Please contact our customer service.' So I emailed them and I guess I'll see what they say. I think this is what I should be doing but I have no idea. I am trying to make it so that when the form is submitted I send a single email to my email address. Everything in the SendInBlue documentation keeps talking about email campaigns, which I don't need.

Answer (score 0):

As Saurabh said - you can make API request to Sendinblue server which will send the email to you from their backend. You can send data from your form using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) module very straightforward. You need to write javascript for collecting all field values from form in one object and then send it to destination url.

Comment: How could I  change the code that I have in order to do this, and what javascript would I have to write

Comment: I wouldn’t complain on a react code if it’s ok for you and you don’t want to dive into to refactor. At first, you need to create a function which will be fired on submit (like handleSubmit, it will receive form data with first argument), then will send it by fetch to sendinblue or whatever API you want.

Comment: You can check first article I found about sending data from react to API server - https://medium.com/@everdimension/how-to-handle-forms-with-just-react-ac066c48bd4f

Comment: I'm going to need to see some code if you want the bounty. I've looked around online for a while about how to do this and can't figure it out, there's probably something that seems obvious to everyone else that I'm just oblivious to and that's why none of the tutorials make sense to me