# EmailJS not sending email, Service ID is invalid error

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I am trying to setup EmailJS for my project.. I am currently getting 'FAILED' logged when I submit, but I can not figure out why? Any help would be great thanks!

```js
function sendMail(contactForm) {
    emailjs.send("gmail", "rosie", {
        "from_name": contactForm.name.value,
        "from_email": contactForm.emailaddress.value,
        "project_request": contactForm.projectsummary.value
    })
    .then(
        function(response) {
            console.log("SUCCESS", response);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("FAILED", error);
        }
    );
    return false;  // To block from loading a new page
}
```

```html
   <form onsubmit="return sendMail(this);">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="fullname" placeholder="Name" required/>
      <input type="text" name="emailaddress" class="form-control" id="emailaddress" placeholder="Email" required/>
      <textarea rows="5" name="projectsummary" class="form-control" id="projectsummary" placeholder="Project Description" required></textarea>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary center-block">Send Project Request</button>
  </form>
```

[image: Email JS Dashboard]
[image: Console log ERROR]

Comment: check that the service id is correct. The server is responding saying it is invalid.

Comment: [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795125/how-to-send-email-from-my-react-web-application/61582486#61582486) where I explain in detail how to use emailJS with React. Might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error text says that your **service ID** is incorrect. So you need to change your **service ID** and replace it with something in your dashboard.
The following link will help you:
https://www.emailjs.com/docs/rest-api/send/